# Plot on a range by using restricted number of points

Tags: plotting, approximation, discrete

Suppose some function. I need to plot it on the given range, but using the finite number of points. After that I need to approximate obtained discrete plot by the curve. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I think we need more detail here. An example data set, an example function, and a description of the desired output. However, you can specify a `PlotRange` when plotting, and you can either interpolate your data using `Interpolation` or fit your data to a function using `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: @march : thank you for paying the attention. My input function is NIntegrate[f[x,m],{x,a,b}] with f[x,m] being very-very complicated function, and m being the parameter. The integration is very-very slow, however successful for given m. But when I try to plot this quantity as the function of m, this takes so long time that I don't want to wait. Therefore, I want to restrict the number of plot points, then to obtain discrete plot, and then replace the discrete points by continuous curve.

Comment: @march : I've found MaxPlotPoints in documentation (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html), and (IT SEEMS THAT) this is almost what I want. But I don't know how to eliminate points from the plot and to have only continuous interpolated curve.

Comment: Well, you can just do `ListLinePlot`, which will join your points by lines? Just make a `Table` of values for your function (say, `lst = Table[{m, NIntegrate[f[x,m],{x,a,b}]}, {m, 1, 5, 0.1}]` or something), and then `ListLinePlot[lst]`.

Comment: @march : what I want is to plot only this line, without the points by using which the line was generated.

Comment: That's what `ListLinePlot` does. I recommend that you peruse the *Mathematica* documentation. One of the best ways to learn *Mathematica* is to go to, say the documentation page for `Plot`, look at the examples, scope, etc. and then scroll down to the bottom to look at the related functions with links to their documentation pages.

Comment: @march : but the examples provided by the link show plot with included points and the line.

Comment: That's because they used the option `Mesh -> All`. Go to the documentation page for `Plot`.

Comment: @march : thank you! And sorry for tedious questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the workflow that you seek.

I will use a simple `f[x,m]` but it should work for the complex one of your actual problem.

### Step 1 - Define f[x,m]

```
f[x_, m_] := m Cos[x]

Plot[f[x, 2], {x, -π/2, π/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Step 2 - Define the intF

`intF` is the function that integrates `f[x,m]` over the limits `a` to `b`.

```
intF[m_, a_, b_] := NIntegrate[f[x, m], {x, a, b}]
```

A test result is:

```
intF[2, -π/2, π/2]

(* 4. *)
```

### Step 3 - Make a table of intF results

Create a table of the input, `m` and the result, `intF[m, a, b]`. The table variable is `m` and the integration limits, `a` and `b` are assumed to be known. Set the step to the increment of the points that you desire (one can use a list as the input increment to `Table` to precisely control the desired points).

In the example below the step was set to 0.1

```
intFlist = Table[{m, intF[m, -π/2, π/2]}, {m, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]

(* {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.6}, {0.4, 0.8}, {0.5, 1.},
    {0.6, 1.2}, {0.7, 1.4}, {0.8, 1.6}, {0.9, 1.8}, {1.0, 2.},
    {1.1, 2.2}, {1.2, 2.4}, {1.3, 2.6}, {1.4, 2.8}, {1.5, 3.},
    {1.6, 3.2}, {1.7, 3.4}, {1.8, 3.6}, {1.9, 3.8}, {2.0, 4.}} *)
```

### Step 4 - ListLinePlot

Plot the table using `ListLinePlot`. This should produce a smooth curve assuming that you have sufficient density in your input points.

```
ListLinePlot[intFlist]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]